# How to find first row where its event time is within a given range?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have two dataframes: the first contains events from the OS scheduler, let's call it `sched`; and the second contains CPU C-state transitions, let's call it `cstate`.

On `sched` I have things such as process name, event timestamp, CPU, and other (irrelevant for now) data.

On `cstate` I have CPU, Previous C-state, Current C-State, Entry timestamp, Exit timestamp.

I want to find which process might have caused a given CPU to wake up from C4 state (the lowest power state for this scenario). The way that I'm thinking about this is group `cstate` by cpu, filter by previous state equal to 'C4', then `loc()` both entry and exit timestamps. This is the easy part.

The difficulty is using these timestamps to, for each CPU, extract the very first process name that's after entry timestamp and before exit timestamp. I could only do this with a `for` loop, but that kills performance.

I have something like below:

```
for cpu in range(8):
    for (i, e) in enumerate(entry_timestamps):
        sched.loc[sched['CPU'] == cpu].between(e, exit_timestamps[i],
                                               inclusive='both').head(1)['process_name']
```

(this may not be exactly correct, I don't have access to the original code at the moment, but it gives the general idea)

Is there a way, with `pandas` to achieve this without these `for` loops?

Just for reference, here's an idea of the data (fake data, but serves the purpose):

`sched`

| CPU | Process | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | foo | 0.0034347 |
| 0 | bar | 0.0036777 |
| 1 | foo | 0.0041122 |

...

`cstate`

| CPU | previous | current | entry | exit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | C4 | C0 | 0.0034005 | 0.0043267 |
| 1 | C4 | C0 | 0.0046505 | 0.0053889 |
| 2 | C4 | C0 | 0.0054005 | 0.0055007 |

...

Comment: What is the expected answer here ?

Comment: A vectorized method for achieving what the nested `for` loops are doing. In fact, vectorizing the inner `for` loop is probably enough.

Comment: For the data above, for example, I should have a pd Series containing [0, foo, 0.0034347]. But basically, I want the very first item from `sched` for each CPU that's within each of the ranges given by `cstate`, also grouped by CPU. Let's say CPU0 has 100 transitions from C4 to C0, then we would fetch the 100 rows from `sched` for CPU0 where the time is within each of the 100 ranges from `cstate`.